# Regulatory domain changed to country CA (I'm BR)

Tags: wireless, syslog, logs

I'm learning some things about the logs to know if everything in the computer is running normally.

But, in these days, my syslog have been filled with messages like:

```
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.572456] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CA
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574463] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: CA
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574466] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574467] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574469] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574470] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574471] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 31 16:56:41 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 9743.574472] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
```

I already searched in these forums about this, but normally people had problems with it along with some Wireless conection problems too (apparently this is not happening here).
Anyway I would like to know some things:

1 - I'm in the region BR, but what if my region changes to CA? Anything that can lower my security can happen(in other words, is there any problem with that)?

2 - [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81762/whats-going-on-with-my-wireless) person probably had the same problems like me, and he got an answer to fix it (and looks like the logs stopped appearing), but since he's Ubuntu version is older, should I use the same methods or I should search for a new method?

Thank you guys for helping me and sorry if there's another question like this one.

Answer (score 1):

This has absolutely nothing to do with security, this is to enforce compliance with local laws.

Install `crda` like this

```
sudo apt-get install crda
sudo vi /etc/default/crda
```

and then change the line REGDOMAIN= to your country code, eg.

```
REGDOMAIN=BR
```

and restart.

Comment: Before doing what you said, just let me ask: What if I don't change the region? Does that make too much difference? Also, I forgot to tell that the region keeps changing from BR to CA and CA to BR.

Comment: If you don't change the domain, you're not in compliance with the law: You may be using frequencies that are reserved for military or other use. This means that you're breaking the law and operating your wireless illegally. That said, I've never ever heard of a case where someone had to put up with law enforcement, let alone prosecutors. If I were you, I'd do nothing - but this statement is purely informational and comes without any warranty...

Comment: Right now, strangely, the domain keep changing from BR to BR (yeah, the same). I will probably do nothing, if it keeps like that.